# Python interaction with lotus quickr database

Tags: python, lotus

I would like to write a python script to copy an entire lotus quickr database to my local hard drive.

For me, a user I can access quickr through an intranet site, and also through quickr connector, a program which allows me to access the database content through windows explorer.  Both of these options are painfully slow, I'd rather copy the entire folder structure to my local disk

¿How can access the quickr database to do this from Python or any scripting language?

Answer (score 0):

QuickR has a nice [API](http://www.lotus.com/ldd/lqwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=API%20Documentation) but that probably won't help you, if either the server or your network is slow, which I suspect. Talk to your admins, maybe they can help.

Comment: Actually it would help me.  If I can copy the DB to my local drive, just once, no matter how slow it is, from then on I'll be able to quickly browse for the data I need from my hard disc instead of through quick.

Comment: Ah, OK. If the content is not changing all the time, this is of course a viable workaround. If this answer helps, pls. upvote and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for bringing this back to life... Any luck on solving this issue?